# Unable to conduct variable importance in r

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to test the variable importance before running the actual regression. But, when I attempt to do so, I get this error:

Error in varImp(regressor, scale = FALSE) :
trying to get slot "responses" from an object (class "randomForest.formula") that is not an S4 object

I've tried looking up the error, but there wasn't much information available online. What can I do to fix this?

```
all = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/massShootings/main/all.csv')

# Check Variable importance with randomForest

regressor <- randomForest::randomForest(total_victims ~ . , data = all, importance=TRUE) # fit the random forest with default parameter
caret::varImp(regressor, scale = FALSE) # get variable importance, based on mean decrease in accuracy
```

Comment: Using this exact code with the `randomForest` package loaded in works for me without any issues.

Comment: Why am I getting this error! I've ran it exactly as I'm showing here. I also restarted my R session. It didn't clear the issue

Comment: Outdated R/packages?

Comment: Did you try to use the `importance` function from randomForest package?

Comment: I have not, but the suggestion someone made on my post seemed to do the trick. Not sure how it fixed it, but it did!